# save a user's report parameter choices so that it can be used again?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

Is it possible to save a user's report parameter choices so that it can be used again, let's say a week later when the user wants to run the report again?

I am using SSRS reporting services in my asp.net(C#) application and using report viewer to display report in website. I want to make some personilization to reports interface. I want users to save his report parameters and give it any name, so that he can generate report any time in future.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [solution on Codeplex](http://rsparamlogcache.codeplex.com/) for a way of building reports to store the users last used parameters as the default choice next time they run the reports.

However it sounds like you actually want to store the report itself for future reference, including a history of different report results. If so, then you may want to look at [Report Snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156325.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I am looking for something different. I want to save selected parameters in database so that I can use it later. I found one good link related to my requirements http://andrusdevelopment.blogspot.ca/2012/01/ssrs-saving-user-settings-from-report.html

Comment: Well the link you provided there looks to do something very similar to the solution on Codeplex - they both store the user's last used parameters so they can be used as defaults next time the report runs.

Answer (score 0):

If your case (report) is not too complicated, try follow this document and see if it helps. I have applied to a couple reports with this and work well. [iParameter SSRS - Report Parameter Saving](https://media.wix.com/ugd/f763a1_8d529cd6617f477c87aac97b3d04a7e4.pdf)